# Numerical approximation of divergent double integral with convergent analytical solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I have limited knowledge of calculus, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have an awkwardly large double integral which I would like to approximate numerically. The double integral calculates the magnetic flux generated by a perfect dipole through a helicoid of length L and radius R, excluding some constants.

[Figure of the helicoid over which the flux is calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg67a.png)

The double integral which I am interested in approximating is a modification of a much simpler integral which takes the form

$$\int_{0}^{L}\int_{0}^{R}\rho\frac{9\rho^2x-6x^3}{(x^2+\rho^2)^{7/2}}d\rho dx$$

Since both equations represent physical quantities, I know that they must be convergent. Solving the above equation analytically produces

$$\frac{R^2}{(L^2+R^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{R}$$

which will clearly produce a reasonable answer. However, when integrating numerically, there is a singularity at $x=0$ and $\rho=0$ where the helicoid meets the center of the dipole, which is also where the flux approaches infinity. This cannot be accounted for with any of the typical quadrature methods of numerical integration.

**Is there a technique I can apply to calculate this integral numerically, or is it only solvable analytically?**

If it would help you to understand why I want to avoid manipulating the integral analytically, here is the integral which I would like to ultimately apply the procedure to:

Given

$$f(x,\rho)=2x^2+2Rr+2R\rho\cos(kx)-R^2-r^2-2r\rho\cos(kx)-\rho^2$$

$$f'(x,\rho)=4x-2R\rho k\sin(kx)+2r\rho k\sin(kx)$$

$$g(x,\rho)=(x^2+(R-r-\rho\cos(kx))^2+\rho^2\sin^2(kx))^{5/2}$$

$$g'(x,\rho)=5(k\rho(R-r)\sin(kx)+x)g^{3/5}(x,\rho)$$

the integral is expressed as

$$\int_{0}^{L}\int_{0}^{R}\rho\frac{f'(x,\rho)g(x,\rho)-f(x,\rho)g'(x,\rho)}{g^2(x,\rho)}d\rho dx$$

This is all related to a paper I'm writing that expands on [the model of a simple electromagnetic train developed by N. Criado and C. Alamo](https://www.doi.org/10.1119/1.4933295). They outline the procedure for modifying the model at the end of the very last footnote on the last page, but no details are given. I have already contacted the authors and I'm waiting for a response, but since this is time-sensitive, I'm hedging my bets by posting here, too.

Comment: The double integral diverges, while one of the iterated integrals converges. You can define $H(x) = \int_0^R h(x, \rho) d\rho$ and consider $\int_0^L H(x) dx$, which is well-defined and can be evaluated numerically.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a cheap answer - in short, I hope you have access to Mathematica, since it has some powerful inbuilt functions for dealing with integrals with singularities. First of all, check the sign on the "analytic solution" - I believe it is in fact the negative of the integral. I made a table of values using Mathematica's `NIntegrate` function and then another table simply using the formula given, up to 15 digits of precision. Here are the results. First the values obtained with the formula:
[image: formula values]

And now the values obtained with `NIntegrate`, using the same lables as before
(sorry my table formatting skills aren't the best)

[image: nintegrate values]

And the diffrerences in their magnitude:

[image: errors]

To see the numbers more clearly, right click the image and select "open image in new tab". I think we can all agree the error is pretty negligible - only occurring in the 12th to 15th decimal place.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the analytic solution had the wrong signs. I've corrected my original post. Thank you for your contribution; I'll look into Mathematica's approach.